# WP8 Contact Asynchronous Search - Return only contacts with a phone number?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am in the process of developing an app which requires a custom contact list. So far, the app queries contacts, displays them all in a listbox, allows multiple selection and for now just writes all selected phone numbers to the debugger output. One thing I have noticed though is that all contacts are available after this sync search, so some of them don't contain phone numbers.

Now, on android, a boolean operator exists to filter contacts - this is contact.HasPhoneNumber and makes life very easy for querying contacts.....so far, I can't find any equivalent for windows. I would really appreciate any help.

Below is the code in question for your perusal, along with Accompanying XAML.

Thank you

**contact.cs**

```
public partial class contact : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public class CustomContact
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }

            public CustomContact()
            {
            }

            //CTOR that takes in a Contact object and extract the two fields we need (can add more fields)
            public CustomContact(Contact contact)
            {
                Name = contact.DisplayName;
                var number = contact.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault();
                if (number != null)
                    Number = number.PhoneNumber;
                else
                    Number = "";
            }
        }

        public contact()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void showContacts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Contacts cons = new Contacts();

            //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
            cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

            //Start the asynchronous search.
            cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
        }

        void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something with the results.
            MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
            try
            {
                //Bind the results to the user interface.
                ContactResultsData.DataContext = e.Results;

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                //No results
            }

            if (ContactResultsData.Items.Any())
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results";
            }
            else
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
            }
        }



        private void ContactResultsData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Contact contact = ContactResultsData.SelectedItem as Contact;
            if (contact != null)
            {
                CustomContact customContact = new CustomContact(contact);
            }
        }

        public void saveContacts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<CustomContact> listOfContacts = new List<CustomContact>();

            listOfContacts = ContactResultsData.SelectedItems.Cast<Contact>().Select(x => new CustomContact()
            {
                Number = x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault() != null ? x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber : "",
                Name = x.DisplayName
            }).ToList();


            foreach (var c in listOfContacts)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(c.Number.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="AppName" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="contacts" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,10" >

                <TextBlock Name="ContactResultsLabel" Text="results are loading..." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <ListBox Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="436" Margin="12,0" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="ContactResults" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="showButton" Content="Show Contacts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218" Height="90" Margin="0,531,0,0" Click="showContacts"/>
            <Button x:Name="saveButton" Content="Save Contacts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="238,531,0,0" Width="218" Height="90" Click="saveContacts"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

***EDIT***

So, I figured it out!

Adding this code:

```
var filteredContacts = new List<Contact>();

  foreach (var contact in e.Results)
  {
    filteredContacts.AddRange((from phoneNumber in contact.PhoneNumbers
                where phoneNumber.Kind == PhoneNumberKind.Mobile
            select contact).Select(cont => (Contact)cont));
  }
```

To the search completed event handler filters the contacts just how I wanted!!