# Append contacts in contact list in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to add more that one contacts to contact list from a xml file, but saveContactTask.Show();
added one contact to contact list, Please anyone tell me how to resolve this issue .

**This is my code:**

private void AddContacts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        using (IsolatedStorageFile istf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream istfs = istf.OpenFile("MyContacts.xml",FileMode.Open))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(istfs);
                var query = from d in doc.Root.Descendants("Contacts")
                            select new
                            {
                                firstName = d.Element("name").Value,
                                mobilePhone = d.Element("phone").Value
                            };

                foreach (var po in query)
                {

                    saveContactTask.FirstName = po.firstName;
                    saveContactTask.MobilePhone = po.mobilePhone;
                    saveContactTask.Show();


                }

            }
      }
```

Comment: I THINK THIS LINK MIGHT HELP YOU 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426871/wp8-contact-asynchronous-search-return-only-contacts-with-a-phone-number?rq=1][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426871/wp8-contact-asynchronous-search-return-only-contacts-with-a-phone-number?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SaveContactTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394013(v=vs.105).aspx) class is designed to add only one contact at a time and Show() function is asynchronous. You can't add second contact until the first call will be finished. Your code should be rewritten to react on `saveContactTask.Completed += new EventHandler<SaveContactResult>(saveContactTask_Completed);` event and start adding the second(etc) contact only when the previous is finished. There is possibility, that new `SaveContactTask` should be used for the second(etc) contact, bear it in mind.

Try something like this (it's only a sample of idea):

```
private List<Contact> listToAdd;
private SaveContactTask saveTask;

saveTask.Completed += addComplete;

void addComplete(...)
{
   if ( listToAdd.Count > 0 )
   {
       Contact contact = listToAdd[0];
       listToAdd.RemoveAt(0);
       saveTask. (set values from contact)
       saveTask.Show();
   }
}
```

Comment: After adding first contact successfully its coming out of the foreach loop, how to fix this issue? Rather than foreach shall I go for any other solution?

Comment: Yes, you need another solution. You're wokring in UI thread and you can't stop it and wait untill the operation will be completed. Try to create a loop with class level variables in saveContactTask.Completed function.